# remove the link between clang++ and g++ on macos mojave

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang++, macos-mojave

So I recently switched to mac and wanted to make a game with SDL2 and C++ and when I compiled some basic code to make a blank window with g++ it gave me an error with clang, I found out that clang links to GCC and g++, is there a way to remove this link so I can compile with g++? I installed it with Homebrew.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What I am exactly asking is how can I remove the link between clang++ and g++ on macOS Mojave